# Orthogonalize method, keeping to binary vectors

Tags: vector

The built in function:

`Orthogonalize[m]`

where m is a list of vectors returns a orthogonal basis for m. However, I want to stick to the binary field. However, I tried this:

`Orthogonalize[m,Mod[#1.#2,2]&]`

But this just still gives a set of vectors with negative coordinates.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of a set of vectors where your proposal fails, and what the answer ought to be?

Comment: Will vectors that are self-orthogonal be problrmatic for your purposes? if not, could just do Gram-Schmidt without the normalization part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define the inner product modulo $2$:

```
orthogonalize[a_] := Mod[Orthogonalize[a, Mod[#1.#2, 2] &], 2]
```

**Example:**

```
(m = Union[orthogonalize[RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {500, 64}]] ]) // ArrayPlot
```

[image: Orthogonal basis]

Check orthogonality:

```
Mod[m . Transpose[m], 2] // ArrayPlot
```

[image]